# What is the difference of -a and -e in bash's conditional expressions?

Tags: bash, shell, test

From `man bash`:

```
CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
[...]
       -a file
              True if file exists.
[...]
       -e file
              True if file exists.
```

1. So what is the difference between `[ -a $FILE ]` and `[ -e $FILE ]`, if any?
2. If there is no real difference, why do two flags for the same purpose exist?

Comment: Only the developers would know #2---unless they shared their reasoning to the community.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `bash`, with context of two arguments `test` command, `-a file` and `-e file` are the same. But they have some difference, because `-a` is also a binary operator.

`-e` unary is defined by POSIX, but `-a` unary isn't. POSIX only defines `-a` binary (See [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) POSIX).

POSIX defines three arguments `test` behaviour:

> 3 arguments:
>
> - If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1
>     and $3.
> - If $1 is '!', negate the two-argument test of $2 and $3.
> - If $1 is '(' and $3 is ')', perform the unary
>     test of $2. On systems that do not support the XSI option, the results are unspecified if $1 is '(' and $3 is ')'.
> - Otherwise, produce unspecified results.

So `-a` also leads to strange result:

```
$ [ ! -a . ] && echo true
true
```

`-a` is considered as binary operator in context of three arguments. See [Bash FAQ question E1](ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/FAQ).
POSIX also mentions that `-a` is get from KornShell but was changed later to `-e` because it makes confusing between `-a` binary and `-a` unary.

> The -e primary, possessing similar functionality to that provided by
>   the C shell, was added because it provides the only way for a shell
>   script to find out if a file exists without trying to open the file.
>   Since implementations are allowed to add additional file types, a
>   portable script cannot use:
>
> test -b foo -o -c foo -o -d foo -o -f foo -o -p foo
>
> to find out if foo is an existing file. On historical BSD systems, the
>   existence of a file could be determined by:
>
> test -f foo -o -d foo
>
> but there was no easy way to determine that an existing file was a
>   regular file. An early proposal used the KornShell -a primary (with
>   the same meaning), but this was changed to -e because there were
>   concerns about the high probability of humans confusing the -a primary
>   with the -a binary operator.

`-a` binary is also marked as obsolescent, because it leads to some ambiguous expression, which has greater than 4 arguments. With these >4 arguments expression, POSIX defines the result is unspecified.

Comment: Cool to know! Now it's a bit more clear :)!

Answer (score 9):

> .1. So what is the difference between [ -a $FILE ] and [ -e $FILE ], if any?

There is no difference at all.

In line `505-507` in `test.c` of the bash version `4.2.45(1)-release`:

```
case 'a':           /* file exists in the file system? */
case 'e':
  return (sh_stat (arg, &stat_buf) == 0);
```

That indicates that there is no real difference between both flags.

> .2. If there is no real difference, why do two flags for the same purpose exist?

See [cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147736/72471).

Comment: On the other hand, given that `-a` is *also* a boolean operator (and) in bash, it seems bug prone to add this additional meaning that is completely redundant; I'd guess it is more related to compatibility to some other implementation and/or compatibility with earlier versions that didn't have `-e`.

Comment: @celtschk - *it* is not bugprone, but the shell's parser may be. POSIX specifies the `-a` and `-o` booleans for `[ test ]`. But *some* shells *(like `bash`)* sucked at distinguishing an argument from an operator and the `[ test ]` results were unreliable. Since then POSIX has required that any compliant shell handle at least 4 arguments within the `[ test ]` brackets.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer I have found is this one, from a StackOverflow question:

- [bash if -a vs -e option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321352/435352) (answered by [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb))

> `-a` is deprecated, thus isn't listed in the manpage for
>   `/usr/bin/test` anymore, but still in the one for bash. Use `-e` . For
>   single '[', the bash builtin behaves the same as the `test` bash
>   builtin, which behaves the same as `/usr/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/test`
>   (the one is a symlink to the other). Note the effect of `-a` depends
>   on its position: If it's at the start, it means `file exists`. If it's
>   in the middle of two expressions, it means logical `and`.
>
> `[ ! -a /path ] && echo exists` doesn't work, as the bash manual
>   points out that `-a` is considered a binary operator there, and so the
>   above isn't parsed as a `negate -a ..` but as a `if '!' and '/path' is
>   true` (non-empty). Thus, your script always outputs `"-a"` (which
>   actually tests for files), and `"! -a"` which actually is a binary
>   `and` here.
>
> For `[[`, `-a` isn't used as a binary `and` anymore (`&&` is used
>   there), so its unique purpose is to check for a file there (although
>   being deprecated). So, negation actually does what you expect.