How to workaround edge case with bash test builtin when a variable value is `>`
The following produces a bash: test: too many arguments exception in test, with exit status 2:
v='>'
test -n "$v" -a yes '!=' no # bash: test: too many arguments
echo $? # 2

test -n '>' -a 1 -eq 1 # bash: test: too many arguments
echo $? # 2

[ -n '>' -a 1 -eq 1 ] # bash: [: too many arguments
echo $? # 2

[[ -n '>' -a 1 -eq 1 ]]
# bash: syntax error in conditional expression
# bash: syntax error near `-a'
echo $? # 2

It works without the -a, and as such, it works using && instead of the -a:
v='>'
test -n "$v"
echo $? # 0

[ -n "$v" ]
echo $? # 0

test -n "$v" && test yes '!=' no
echo $? # 0

[ -n "$v" ] && [ yes '!=' no ]
echo $? # 0

There is no mention of this peculiar behaviour inside the documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test
Known versions affected:
GNU bash, version 5.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0)
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22)
If this is intended behaviour, then what is the suitable workaround?

Should I always use && instead of -a?
Should I use a parameter replacement? e.g. test -n "${v//>/.}" -a 1 -eq 1
Is there another suggestion?


You shouldn't be using -a at all, it's a mess: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676611/70524 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147736/70524

Better yet, use [[ ]] since you have tagged this bash, since that won't confuse variables with operators.

@muru same deal with [[, [[ -n $v -a 'yes' '!=' 'no' ]] throws bash: syntax error in conditional expression, bash: syntax error near '-a' and [[ -n "$v" ]] && [[ 'yes' '!=' 'no' ]] throws bash: conditional binary operator expected, bash: syntax error near '!='

That's the main reason why the -a and -o binary operators are deprecated and should not be used.

@balupton well, yes, because -a is unusable. Also, why are you quoting != there? That will make [[ think it's not an operator.

[[ supports && for logical conjunction without issue. Use [[ ... && ... ]] or [ ... ] && [ ... ], and forget about -a entirely.

Could use "${var:+x}" instead. It substitutes "x" instead of the value if the value is set and nonempty.

Based on the documentation, this does look like a bug, but I don’t have an explanation. ('<' causes this too.)
However I do have a workaround. Switching the expressions works, assuming their order isn’t significant:
test 1 -eq 1 -a -n '>'

Ultimately it’s better to use the && form — see this answer to “Bash negation of -a (file exists) does not change result, whereas for ! -e changes result” or this answer to “What is the difference of -a and -e in bash's conditional expressions?” for details.
